# Applying sort descriptor to NSFetchRequest created from template

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a fetch request defined within my core data model called "RemainingGaneProjections". I want to execute that fetch request and sort the results by one of the entity's attributes. My code looks like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *projectionsRequest = [model fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"RemainingGameProjections"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"confidence" ascending:NO];
[projectionsRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

When I try to execute this code it crashes with the following message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't modify a named fetch request in an immutable model.'
```

I have confirmed in the debugger that this crash happens when I execute the setSortDescriptors method on my NSFetchRequest. I haven't been able to figure out why this happens.

Any explanations for what is happening here? Is there another approach I should be using when retrieving data that needs to be sorted?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found the answer myself in the Apple documentation of all places. Because my fetch request has no substitution parameters, I used the fetchRequestTemplateForName method instead of fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName. As it turns out, the Core Data programming guide says this:

> If the template does not have substitution variables, you must either:
>
> 1. Use fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:substitutionVariables: and pass
>      nil as the variables argument;
> 2. Use fetchRequestTemplateForName: and
>      copy the result. If you try to use the fetch request returned by
>      fetchRequestTemplateForName:, this generates an exception ("Can't
>      modify a named fetch request in an immutable model").

I modified my fetch request initialization to do this:

```
NSFetchRequest *projectionsRequest = [[model fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"RemainingGameProjections"] copy];
```

and now everything works as expected.

Comment: And I assume you also added a corresponding `release` for `projectionsRequest`.

Comment: Nope - I'm using ARC for this project ;)

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation:

NSSortDescriptor *ageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES];

NSSortDescriptor *hireDateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"hireDate" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ageDescriptor, hireDateDescriptor];

NSArray *sortedArray = [employeesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html