# fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName returns nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

[image]

I added FETCH REQUESTS and I write the below code.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [delegate.managedObjectModel 
   fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:@"isUser" 
              substitutionVariables:nil];
```

but fetchRequest returns nil.
Help me!

Comment: perhaps this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438263/fetchrequestfromtemplatewithname-variables

Comment: i've already read that question. but i can't solve my problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on `fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:`:

> The variables dictionary must provide values for **all** the variables. If you want to test for a nil value, use [NSNull null].

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [delegate.managedObjectModel 
  fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:@"isUser" 
  substitutionVariables:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      @"type", [NSNull null], nil]];
```

Maybe you are looking for `fetchRequestTemplateForName:` which works without substitution variables.

Comment: I tried fetchRequestTemplateForName:, but the situation is same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425713/applying-sort-descriptor-to-nsfetchrequest-created-from-template

I read this article, and revised my code. but all is same.